# Get a mouse following action like in Minecraft using C#

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouse

I am trying to make a 3D game using Visual C# Express 2010. I am using XNA 4.0 in this software.

In this game, you have to be able to look left, right, up, and down using the mouse. (1st Person view, I just want to rotate the camera)

As long as the game is running, like Minecraft I want the mouse to stay in the window, and only when the esc key is pressed, does the mouse become visible.

Can anyone tell me the correct commands to track mouse motion, and to keep the mouse in the window, or point me toward a good tutorial for this?

Comment: 2 questions: what UI are you using (XNA, Unity, Winforms, etc), and could you please be a bit more specific about "looking" (first person or third person)?

Comment: @bubbinator XNA 4.0, and I'm just trying to rotated the Camera object

Comment: Thank you. One last (hopefully) question, with the movement do you want to mouse movement to be absolute or emulate a joystick?

Comment: @bubbinator I would prefer absolute, but if you think emulating a joystick is better, I am open to suggestion.

Comment: You probably could implement both fairly easily. I'm doing some digging about how to keep the mouse cursor in the window, but the mouse stuff isn't that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got some information for you. You can use `Mouse.SetPosition` method to keep the cursor within the bounds of the window. Just be sure to only call that when the window is in focus and not minimized. Also keep in mind that the position is relative to the top-left corner of the *window*.

Now for the movement, that is simply comparing the current mouse state with the center of the window. Then you'd need to call `SetPosition` to put the cursor back in the center of the window. So something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    Rectangle center = this.Window.ClientBounds;
    MouseState newState = Mouse.GetState();
    double angle = Math.Atan2(newState.Y - center.Y, newState.X - center.X);
    // Change camera angle. Needs to be tuned to your wants most likely.
    Mouse.SetPosition((int)center.X, (int)center.Y);
}
```

On a side note, there is a more dedicated version of this website: [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com). Also, I must put in a disclaimer, this was a learning experience for me and unfortunately I lack the time to test the above code.

Comment: This works perfectly for Left/Right. However, for up/down it only goes a few degrees, after that the controls spazz out for all directions (flipping or not working at all) if I exceed some distance

Comment: Sounds like it might be the camera reorienting code. Have you tried to give it a true single direction test? You may need to implement keyboard controls for that. Other than that I can't give you any direction without seeing some more code.

Comment: OK, it looks there is an issue with my rotation code. I'll open a new post for this. Thanks.